# Send Welcome Email enable when admin create user

Tags: magento-1.9, php, admin-user

i am using magento(1.9.0.1), when admin create a user, the user will get welcome e-mail based on the "Send Welcome Email" make checked, but default in my pack its disable state, i can not able to checked it.

how to make enable, any idea please suggest me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkbox should be disabled if you are in a multistore environment and you don't have website selected when creating a customer. Select a website and it should become enabled.

Comment: thanks you for your support work, can you please answer the following question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67024/welcome-e-mail-content-change-based-on-user-group

Comment: How can I do the same in Magento 8.1? any idea?